# How to handle JavaScript events (e.g. 'link_to :remote') the Rails Way?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to handle JavaScript events the Rails way. That is, for example, given I have the following

```
link_to('destroy', article_path(@article), :method => :delete, :remote => true)
```

when I click on the above generated link then I would like the `success` JS event to update the page content by removing the deleted article DOM element. The AJAX response, whatever it is, should be ignored.

I am aware of the existence of the [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) file but I don't how to use it in order to accomplish what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a wiki page https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax with explanation of ujs custom events. Here is a little example in your case:

```
$('a').on 'ajax:success', -> alert 1
```

**UPD** If you want to prevent XHR response being evaluated, add `data-type=text` attribute to your remote link:

```
link_to('destroy', article_path(@article), :method => :delete, :remote => true, 'data-type' => 'text')
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW: How to ignore the AJAX response at all? That is, on success the AJAX response is a redirect to another page and I would like ignore that redirect.

Comment: Do you say that you have the `destroy.js.erb` responder which contains a `window.location` function?

Comment: No, in my controller I have `format.js { render :js => "window.location.replace('#{articles_path}');" }`. I would like to ignore that behavior on `ajax:success`.

Comment: I think I do not have to change the controller and I can just "ignore" the response (in the example case, it is a redirect but it can be whatever) directly within the `ajax:success` callback function. But how to make that?

Comment: Ah, ok, I catch. I think the most clear way is to add `data-type='text'` attribute to you link, In this way response will not be JS evaluated.

Comment: `data-type='text'` does not work as expected. I opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719173/how-to-avoid-to-evaluate-a-javascript-response).