# How to avoid to evaluate a JavaScript response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, unobtrusive-javascript

I am using Ruby on Rails 4. In [my previos question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715384/how-to-handle-javascript-events-of-a-link-to-remote-element-a-la-rails-way) I asked about how to handle JavaScript events of a `link_to :remote` element "a là Rails Way". However I would like to make the AJAX to do *not* evaluate the JavaScript response (whatever it is) so that I can implement my custom behaviors.

In my case the AJAX response that should be ignored is generated by clicking the following link:

```
link_to('destroy', article_path(@article), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :id => 'css_id')
```

On success it will return a JS redirect but I would like to simply catch the success response and do not evaluate the subsequent redirect.

```
$('#css_id').on('ajax:success', function(event, xhr, status) {
  alert("success!");

  \\ Here I would like to do not evaluate the JS response.
});
```

How can I make that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript behavior and just call this behavior in your .js.erb file since you can avoid writing more js codes inside the template. It should be something like this.

EX: in the create.js.html:

```
App.createProdict() #pass the required params.
```

And this App.createProduct is a js behavior.

Comment: Are you saying that I have to implement a new `.js.html` file and to handle things with a `case when` statement in the controller? If so, does it means that the controller will be more complicated? BTW: I thought to ignore the JS response in order to not complicate the controller...